# Does a 7400 IC used as AND-gate use any power when output is 0?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

If I have a simple 7400 IC and using it for a single AND operation, would it consume any power when the AND is false and outputting 0V?

If so, to what degree? 20mA or 20uA?

Comment: While a trivial answer might come from a data sheet, this is actually a question which touches on something worth covering.  In particular, the static consumption of 7400 series TTL is going to be a lot higher than that of a CMOS varient of the same function, where there is theoretically static power consumed but the overwhelming majority of consumption will be during switching.  Also, measuring consumption can be tricky as gates can tend to steal power from their inputs - you almost need to measure the total consumption of a self-contained circuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A traditional 7400 series part will draw 12ma typical, 22ma max with all outputs low. (4ma typical to 8 ma max with all outputs high.)

74LS00 (low-power Schottky) ... 2.4ma typical, 4.4ma max.

74S00 (Schottky) ... 20ma typical, 36ma max.

74HC00 (high speed CMOS) ... 2ua typical, 20ua max.